# Email Templating in yii with MVC itself

Tags: php, yii, template-engine

I am designing an Email controller with actions like actionRegisterEmail and actionForgotPasswordEmail.
This would help me to view the emails in browser also while assigning dummy data if data is not set.

```
class EmailController extends Controller
{
    public $layout='email';

    public function actionForgotEmail(ResetPasswordEmail $forgotModel=null){
        if($forgotModel == null){
            $forgotModel = new ResetPasswordEmail;
            $forgotModel->name = "John Doe" ;
            $forgotModel->link = "a url" ;
        }
        return $this->render('reset_password',$forgotModel);
    }

}
```

When I'll be sending this emails I will be instantiating the controllers and fetching their returned html which they return with $this->render.
The idea is good according to me but yii doesn't allow me to call action methods on instantiated controllers like

```
 $emailController = Yii::app()->createController('email');
 $vary = $emailController->actionForgotEmail($reset);
 todb_and_mail($vary);
```

.
This way I can mail the rendered html and also test with dummy. But I have come across many posts which says do not instantiate controller use components.But I want to have a seperate view and pass data to it.Do we have any more simpler alternative ?

Comment: Check out the mail extension for Yii: http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/mail/, it allows you to use views as the email content

Comment: thanks I didn't use the extension but got the idea :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to help anyone with the same doubt.I instantiated a dummy controller and set its layout and called the render method then.

```
class MailHelper extends CComponent {
    public static function getEmail($view_template,$data){
        $controller = new CController('Email');
        $controller->layout = "email" ;
        return $controller->render($view_template, $data, true);
    }
}
```

This way I can get the functionality of passing variables and data to view.We are using static html for visibility of the view files directly from the browser, this was actually simple I made it complicated to get the other things involved thanks [davey](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2696587/davey) for guiding me right.